# How to broadcast message to many subscribers with ng2-stompjs?

Tags: angular, rabbitmq, stomp

I use @stomp/ng2-stompjs to work with RabbitMQ

Have one publisher

```
this.rxStompService.publish({ destination: this.queue, headers: {receipt: receiptId}, body: message });
```

and can have more than one subscriber

```
this.rxStompService.watch(this.queue).subscribe((message: Message) => {
     this.receivedMessages.push(message.body);
});
```

For the moment if I have opened 2 pages in browser only one of the pages receives the message. How I can set it up to broadcast for all subscribers?

Comment: did you got any thing for that

Comment: I just want to add token in header